# Missing git file

Tags: git

I'm creating repository via web interface by "Repositories / Create new repository". Then I can see it both in web-interface and Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories\

When I check for the options for my repo I see the link to *.git
Something like: General Url http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/MyTest.git

But there is no .git file. Furthermore, there is no .git file on whole HDD
Can anyone tell me, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe your file manager has activated that stupid "feature" to hide file name extension? I am not using MS-Windows myself, but I remember MS built something like this years ago and caused endless frustration with it... Apart from that: how did you clone the repository to your local system?

Comment: Sory, but no. I can see "hidden" files. And I can't clone repo beacuse git-client want to ".git" file. I just create repo on my server but there is no .git and I can't do anything

Comment: First, I was not referring to the visualization of hidden files, but of hidden file names extensions Second, in web technology a link to some object whos name ends with .something does not mean that there has to be a physical file with the same name. Objects may be created on-the-fly when requesting them. This especially makes sense for meta data as in this case. So, what does the link refer to? You did not say that...

Comment: In server web-interface I can see this link: "General Url http://localhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/test.git"
On client side I use "http://<MYIP>/Bonobo.Git.Server/test.git" or "http://<MYIP>:80/Bonobo.Git.Server/test.git" where <MYIP> is my router ip address. There is setting on router to forward request on 80 port to server PC. But anyway git-client says "there is no such file"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried showing hidden files?, the git file on windows is a hidden file. So if you're using windows try going to:

```
1.Windows explorer
     2.Tools
         3.Folder options
             4.View
                5.Files and Folder
                    6.Hidden files and folders
                        *Activate the option "Show hidden files, folders and drives"
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks, but my file browser shows hidden files by default. But there is realy no .git file :(

Comment: Are you sure about the placer where your repos are being saved?, please try this: `git config --global --list`

Comment: Oh, there is some trouble with path:

c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Git>git config --global --list

fatal: unable to read config file 'C:/\Users\ImbaServer/.gitconfig': No such file or directory

Where I can change it?

Comment: "C:/\Users" - I think this double slash - result of russian locale. Anyone know how to fix it?